# echo server example

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I wrote the following code in order to make an echo server (data I write to `stdout` moves from my PC to server and back to my PC). The problem is that echo is not getting displayed on client's terminal. There are 2 `server.cpp` processes running so I know that my connection has been accepted by the server. Tthe full code is [here](http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=d8oUF) so that you can directly copy and run the code. The relevant parts of code are:

#### server.cpp

```
void reflect(int x)
{
    int n;
    int m;
    char data[100];
    cout<<"Entered reflect function"<<endl; //this gets displayed

    n=read(x,data, 100); //***execution is not going beyond this point i.e. read is blocking***
    cout<<"Client sent "<<n<<endl; //this doesn't get displayed 

    if(n>0)
    {
        while(n>0)
        {
            m=write(x,data,n);
            n=n-m;
        }
    cout<<"Successfully echoed back to client"<<endl; //this doesn't get displayed 
    }
}

int main()
{
    sockaddr_in serv;
    bzero(&serv, sizeof(serv));
    serv.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv.sin_port=htons(3345);
    inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &(serv.sin_addr));

    int servfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    int x;
    x=bind(servfd, (sockaddr*)(&serv), sizeof(serv));

    cout<<"Bind returned"<<x<<endl; //this displays x as 0

    listen(servfd, 5);
    sockaddr cli;
    int connfd;
    pid_t id=-1;
    socklen_t siz=sizeof(cli);
    for(;;)
    {
        if(connfd=accept(servfd, &cli, &siz)>=0)
             id=fork();

        if(id==0)
             reflect(connfd);

        else 
             continue;
    }
}
```

#### client.cpp

```
int main()
{
    int clifd;
    clifd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    sockaddr_in serv;
    bzero(&serv, sizeof(serv));
    serv.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv.sin_port=htons(3345);
    inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &(serv.sin_addr));

    connect(clifd, (sockaddr*)(&serv), sizeof(serv));//blocking call
    int n,m;
    char data[100];
    char recvd[100];
    for(;;)
    {
        fgets(data, 100,stdin );
        n=strlen(data);
        cout<<"You have written "<<n<<endl; //this returns the correct value

        if(n>0)
        {
            while(n>0)
            {  
                 m=write(clifd,data,n);
                 n=n-m;
            }
        }

        n=read(clifd, recvd, 100);
        cout<<"Server echoed back "<<n<<endl; //this doesn't get displayed

        if(n>0)
        {
            while(n>0)
            {
                m=fputs(data,stdout);
                fflush(stdout);
                n=n-m;
            }
            //cout<<data<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you rewrite the code and do some checking of the return values of your `socket` `bind` `listen` `read` and `write` function calls. Then you can provide people with a more specific error - at least it shows you have tried to check the source of error

Comment: and some indentation would be nice.

Comment: @mathematician1975...i did say there were two server.cpp processes running...that is only possible if accept returned a value >0...and if accept works, socket. bind and listen are working...i even checked and bind returns 0...i did some searching for error and have edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In server.c, replace this incorrect line:

```
if( connfd=accept(servfd, &cli, &siz) >=0 )
```

with this correct one:

```
if( (connfd=accept(servfd, &cli, &siz)) >=0 )
```

---

*Aside*: What compiler are you using? g++ printed a warning when it saw that line:

```
serv.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
serv.cc:45:43: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
```

I try to always use `-Wall -Werror` when compiling with g++ or gcc.

Comment: @rob...thanx..that worked..but there is a problem now...please take a look at the question...i have updated it

Comment: @rob...i have explained the new problem in another question...please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420177/echo-server-returning-the-same-input-many-times)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `accept` in server.cpp with invalid arguments. The third argument must contain the size of the structure pointed by the second argument:

```
socklen_t siz = sizeof(cli);
for(;;)
{
    if((connfd=accept(servfd, &cli, &siz))>=0)
    ...
```

Comment: @rgerganov...thanks for pointing out...but that didn't solve the problem...i have edited the code...please take a look.

Comment: @avinash you need to surround the assignment with parentheses, see my updated answer.

Comment: @rgerganov....that works...but there is a problem...please see the question...i have updated it

Comment: @rgerganov...i have explained the new problem in another question...please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420177/echo-server-returning-the-same-input-many-times)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, you are inputting 100 characters on the client side via `stdin`?

If not, you are writing less then 100 characters to the server, but the server expects 100 characters, so the server side `read()` blocks.

You might solve this by modifying the client code like so:

```
while (n > 0)
{  
  m = write(clifd, data, sizeof(data));
  ...
```

---

A different approach whould be to split the client->server communication into two part:

1 Send the size of data to be echoed

2 Send the data itself

By doing so you allow the server to adjust the number of characters to read and then echo back.

---

This construct below does not make sense as long you do not check the value returned by `write()` to be `-1`.

The call to `write()` will block until `n` bytes are written or will return `-1` on error. The latter will brake your logic.

```
while (n > 0)
{
  m=write(fd, data, n);
  n = n - m;
}
```

You might like to try something like this:

```
while (n > 0)
{
  m = write(fd, data, n);
  if (0 < m)
    n = n - m;
  else if (errno)
    perror("write()");
}
```

This issue applies to the server as also to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Some indentation would be nice but i also recommend you to re-write it with a check on differents function like said "mathematician1975".
You can fin lots of example on google. and also one in `man accept`.
I recommand you to take a look at : `poll` or `select` to avoid the `fork`

Comment: @luxsypher...thanks for pointing out...but that didn't solve the problem...i have edited the code...please take a look..