# echo server returning the same input many times

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

[image]

I wrote the following code in order to make an echo server (data I write to stdout moves from my PC to server and back to my PC).**The problem is that though echo is getting displayed on client's terminal it is being displayed same number of times as is its length.**

**server.cpp**

```
void reflect(int x)
{
int n;
int m;
char data[100];
cout<<"Entered reflect function"<<endl; 

for(;;)
{
n=read(x,data, 100); 
cout<<"Client sent "<<n<<endl; 

if(n>0)
{
    while(n>0)
    {
        m=write(x,data,n);
        n=n-m;
    }
cout<<"Successfully echoed back to client"<<endl;  
}
}//end of for loop
}

int main()
{
sockaddr_in serv;
bzero(&serv, sizeof(serv));
serv.sin_family=AF_INET;
serv.sin_port=htons(3345);
inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &(serv.sin_addr));

int servfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
int x;
x=bind(servfd, (sockaddr*)(&serv), sizeof(serv));

cout<<"Bind returned"<<x<<endl; //this displays x as 0

listen(servfd, 5);
sockaddr cli;
int connfd;
pid_t id=-1;
socklen_t siz=sizeof(cli);
for(;;)
{
    if((connfd=accept(servfd, &cli, &siz))>=0)
         id=fork();

    if(id==0)
         reflect(connfd);

    else 
         continue;
}
}
```

**client.cpp**

```
int main()
{
int clifd;
clifd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
sockaddr_in serv;
bzero(&serv, sizeof(serv));
serv.sin_family=AF_INET;
serv.sin_port=htons(3345);
inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &(serv.sin_addr));

connect(clifd, (sockaddr*)(&serv), sizeof(serv));
int n,m;
char data[100];
char recvd[100];
for(;;)
{
    fgets(data, 100,stdin );
    n=strlen(data);
    cout<<"You have written "<<n<<endl;

    if(n>0)
    {
        while(n>0)
        {  
             m=write(clifd,data,n);
             n=n-m;
        }
    }

    n=read(clifd, recvd, 100);
    cout<<"Server echoed back "<<n<<endl; 

    if(n>0)
    {
        while(n>0)
        {
            m=fputs(data,stdout);  //gets displayed many times
            cout<<"m is"<<m<<endl; //gets displayed many times
            fflush(stdout);
            n=n-m;
        }
        //cout<<data<<endl;
    }
}
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fputs

Return Value
 On success, a non-negative value is returned.
 On error, the function returns EOF.

Maybe use write instead to  get the number of bytes written

Answer (score 0):

`fputs` prints a C-string, not a single character, so you're printing the whole string once per character in your while loop. Additionally it relies on the string being null-terminated which yours is not. You know the length so you could probably force your own null termination or better still create a `std::string` with the start and length.

Answer (score 0):

This code is actually trying to print the data as many times as there are bytes in the array. It will return the number of bytes written, which is 4. I don't think you need to puts() and fflush in a loop. You could call them once. If you still want to have the while loop, may be you can check the return value (m) and compare with the the length of data (n) and if they are equal, break from loop.

Last while loop can be replaced by

```
fputs(data,stdout);
fflush(stdout);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you process the buffer if new data arrived or not.

You can change this where you read the data:

```
for(;;)
{
    if(fgets(data, 100,stdin )) { /* only process the data, when something arrived. */
        n=strlen(data);
        cout<<"You have written "<<n<<endl;
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The strlen() function gives the number of characters in your input excluding the zero byte that terminates a C style string. You write only n bytes to the server (without a null terminator). Then you read n characters echoed back from the server and never set the remainder of the recvd buffer. So it's printing whatever junk is in memory until it finds a zero.